# R package check return this warning: Sys.setlocale(...) - request to set locale cannot be honored

Tags: r, devtools

When using devtools::check() to check my R packages i get the warning below. This applies to my own humble packages as well as more well reputated cran packages (e.g. https://github.com/hadley/babynames). How to get around this problem?

```
devtools::check()
```

> .
> .
> checking R files for syntax errors ... WARNING
> Warning in Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", oLC_ct) :
> OS reports request to set locale to "Norwegian BokmC%l_Norway.utf8" cannot be honored

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

> locale: >[1] C

Comment: What are your OS and version of R? If it's R pre 4.2 on WIndows then it is a known issue, R didn't support UTF-8, it only started supporting it with 4.2. See official announcements [here](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2021/12/07/upcoming-changes-in-r-4.2-on-windows/) and [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2022/000683.html).

Comment: Thanks for asking, I edited my question by adding this info at the end.